# Error: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'append'

Tags: python

I am getting an error can you guys help me out.

### This is the code:

```
   n1 = [0]
    for x in range(t):
        n1 = n1.append(int(input()))
```

### This is the exact error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/DELL/PycharmProjects/start/jam1.py", line 5, in <module>
    n1 = n1.append(int(input()))
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'append'
```

I will be gratefull if you help me out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`append` does not return a value; it modifies the list in place.

So just do:

```
   n1 = [0]
    for x in range(t):
        n1.append(int(input()))
```

Answer (score 1):

after your first iteration, `n1` will become `None` since `list.append` returns `None`, you may use a list comprehension:

```
n1 = [0] + [int(input()) for _ in range(t)]
```

Answer (score 0):

First answer is solid, here is another alternative:

```py
n1 = [0]
for x in range(2):
    n1 = n1 + [int(input())]
```